# Blue powder around valve and pvc pipes

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pipe, pvc

I found some bluish powder under my sink around the valves and PVC pipe. I found the same thing under two other sinks. There is no sign of water. Anyone have an idea of what this could be? I did have a new water heater installed last month.

[image]

Comment: The blue looks like it's one of the colors that polystyrene foam insulation comes in. It looks like there may be a sheet of foam covered with some sort of putty type material and that a chunk of the putty has broken off and the blue is showing through. That doesn't match up with the blue stuff on the trim collar, though. _That_ part almost looks like toothpaste. Not sure why someone would be brushing their teeth under the sink, though. You say "powder", is it actually a powder that will wipe off or is it stuck on?

Comment: Hi! The powder will wipe off. It feels like baby powder. I haven’t tried cleaning it yet just in case it’s there for a reason. I just bought this house last month.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that someone spilled some baby powder...

There's no reason for a powdery material to be down there - it's not part of the installation process, it's not providing any assistance in keeping plumbing joints sealed.

What it is and why it's there will likely remain a mystery, but it can be safely cleaned up.